Question about existence of solutions to integral equations of the first kind
We have three random variables $U, W, A$ and consider the integral operator. The integral operator $T$ is defined as $$Tf= \int f(w,u)p(w|a)dw = p(u|a).  $$
for any fixed variable $u$, where $p(w|a)$ and $p(u|a)$ are  conditional p.d.f. We want to proof that what assumptions need to be satisfied to make it exist a solution $f$. In fact, we have $W\perp A|U$, therefore we have $$\int p(w|u)p(u|a)du = p(w|a).$$
I don't know if this condition helps with the previous inverse problem. Besides, I investigated the relevant literature, and it seems that Picard's theorem is a necessary and sufficient condition to characterize the existence of a solution to the inverse problem.
